# Put shadows on custom divs without using drop shadow

Tags: html, css

My goal is to get custom divs with a rounded corner inside and then put drop shadows on it because we can't use box-shadow. I have already done this part (see below).
The problem is I've got some lags due to drop shadows because I use Skrollr (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). Is there a way to recreate these shadows on my custom divs without using drop shadows?

You can also modify the way I did the curved corner if it helps.

Thank you for your help!

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.frame {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    margin-top: 12rem;
    
}

.tile1 {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 101.4% 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgb(222,184,135, 0) 105px, coral 105px);
    height: 300px;
}

.tile2 {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -1.4% 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgb(222,184,135, 0) 105px, coral 105px);
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>custom div</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="tile1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="tile2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the issue related to filter property or only Drop-shadow value?

Comment: I never asked myself the question but now I have tried the solution of donkey I still observe some lags so maybe it's because of the filter property. So the question becomes is there a way to get these shadows without the filter property?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use pseudo-element become shadow?

looking different.

see below

```css
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 200vh;
    }

    .frame {
      margin-top: 12rem;
      width: 500px;
      margin:100px auto;
    }

    .tile1 {
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 101.4% 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgb(222, 184, 135, 0) 105px, coral 105px);
      height: 300px;
      filter: drop-shadow(0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
    }

    .tile2 {
      position: relative;
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -1.4% 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgb(222, 184, 135, 0) 105px, coral 105px);
      height: 300px;
    }
    .tile2::after {
      content: '';
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0px;
      left: 8px;
      filter: blur(16px);
      position: absolute;
      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at -1.4% 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgb(222, 184, 135, 0) 105px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 105px);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>custom div</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="tile1"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <div class="tile2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it was a good try but I still have got some lags so now I think it's because of the filter property. Too bad because tweaking some values I managed to get the same result as before. Do you know another solution to recreate these shadows without the filter property?

Comment: A shadow without filter and box-shadow, mh... I will painting a shadow image.and make its looking like the container shadow. but in my test when animation left:0 to left:300px, didn't see lag. perhaps is too many animation move on same time?

Comment: It's because of Skrollr otherwise, of course, there's no lag. And lags only appear on Safari as well I am gonna try to paint it. Thank you!